# RichFaces - style problem (publishing on server)

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

When I run my application directly from development enviroment (eclipse + tomcat 7 at localhost), graphic looks different than when I start it from server (not localhost).

localhost (eclipse, tomcat, firefox 5):
[image]

on server (tomcat, firefox 5):
[image]

All neccessary libraries are in WEB-INF\lib, style.css is also present, project is deployed as WAR file on tomcat server.

Don´t you know where could be the problem?

Comment: Those screens seems to be taken from physically different machines. Isn't the problem just that your server screen supports less colors? Antialiasing on the fonts is also totally missing which suggests a poor graphic card or a remote desktop connection. In that case, this problem is in no way related to CSS/JSF/RichFaces, but just to the hardware used.

Comment: :-) Jo, problem with font was really caused by cleartype effect, problem with color was solved using #BFCDDB instead of InactiveCaption color. Thank you and please make the answer to accept it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences are caused by the difference in the software/hardware of the machine which you used to view the webpage. In the second screen the fonts are not antialiased which means that the operating system of the machine has cleartype/antialiasing turned off or that the graphics card simply doesn't support it. As to the colors, this can happen when the machine doesn't support for example 32k colors, but only 16k or even less. This can be either an operating system setting, or a poor graphics card, or being just a screenshot taken over a remote desktop connection which is usually returned with less colors to save network bandwidth.

They are not caused by CSS/JSF/RichFaces in any way.